# Code outputs unexpected/wrong results in GCC when using char

Tags: c, gcc

I'm fairly new to C and I've been facing some annoying problems while compiling code with GCC (The same exact code that doesn't work on GCC works on visual studio).

Sometimes when I use char with my variables after a few lines of code the value stored in that variable is changed to 0 for some reason. I spent hours tracing what causes my code to run incorrectly and couldn't figure out the reason. Whenever I changed my data type from char to int the code worked as intended. Worth to note that in some instances when I was using char: using volatile or static solved the issue and in other instances changing the variable name (Removing any _ in the name) solved the issue and sometimes deleting #include math.lib and then undo solved the issue and other times in the same code all these changes just stopped working and the outcome was not as expected (the code could work 1 time but when I run it again without changing anything it wouldn't work)

Note: `u8` is `unsigned char` and `s8` is `signed char`.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "...\Projects/type_def.h"
#include "...\Projects/Bitwise_Operations.h"

void continuity();
void Print_Array();
void Scan_Array();
void Sort();
void Binary_Search();
void Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Below(s8 Below_First_Hit);
void Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Above(s8 Above_First_Hit);


u8 NumbertoSearchfor, NumberofElements, * array = NULL;


void main() {

    printf("Please enter the number of elements for the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &NumberofElements);


    array = (u8*)malloc(NumberofElements * sizeof(u8));


    //Asking the user to enter the values to be stored in the array
    printf("Please enter the values stored in the array:\n");
    Scan_Array(array);


    //Sorting the array
    Sort(array);



    //Asking the user to enter the number he wants to search for
    printf("\nPlease enter the number you want to search for: ");
    scanf("%d", &NumbertoSearchfor);




    //Searching for the required number
    Binary_Search();



    //free((void*) arr);

    continuity();
}




void Print_Array() {
    for (u8 i = 0; i < NumberofElements; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}




void Scan_Array() {
    for (u8 i = 0; i < NumberofElements; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
}




//Sorting function
void Sort() {

    for (u8 i = 0; i < (NumberofElements - 1); i++) {
        for (u8 j = 0; j < (NumberofElements - 1) - i; j++) {
            u8 temp;

            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }


    // Printing the sorted array
    printf("\nThe sorted array is: ");
    Print_Array(array);
}

void Binary_Search() {

    u8 start = 0, end = NumberofElements - 1, flag = 0;

    while (start <= end) {

        s8  mid = (start + end) / 2;

        if (NumbertoSearchfor == array[mid]) {
            printf("The number %d was found in elements %d ", NumbertoSearchfor, mid);
            Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Below(mid - 1);
            Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Above(mid + 1);
            flag++;
            break;
        }
        else if (NumbertoSearchfor > array[mid]) {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            end = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("The number %d was not found in this array", NumbertoSearchfor);
    }
}




void Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Below(s8 Below_First_Hit) {


    if ((array[Below_First_Hit] == NumbertoSearchfor) && (Below_First_Hit >= 0)) {
        printf("%d ", Below_First_Hit);
        Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Below(Below_First_Hit - 1);
    }

}

void Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Above(s8 Above_First_Hit) {

    if ((array[Above_First_Hit] == NumbertoSearchfor) && (Above_First_Hit < NumberofElements)) {
        printf("%d ", Above_First_Hit);
        Binary_Search_For_Duplicates_In_NumberofElements_Above(Above_First_Hit + 1);
    }
}







void continuity() {
    u8 cont = 0;
    printf("\nDo you want to continue? Y/N\n");
    scanf(" %c", &cont);

    if ((cont == 'Y') || (cont == 'y')) {
        main();
    }
    else if ((cont == 'N') || (cont == 'n')) {
        printf("Thanks for using our program. Exiting ...");
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid answer.");
        continuity();
    }
}
```

This is my full code. It's supposed to take in the Number of elements for an array from the user then use `malloc` to dynamically allocate the number of bytes needed to make that array then sort the array and used binary search to find a number that a user entered and print the element it was found in. There is 2 other functions to search if the number was found multiple times plus Continuity function is just to check if the user want to re-do the whole thing.

After using multiple `printf` to trace the problem I found that after this line:

```
scanf("%d", &NumbertoSearchfor);
```

the value in `NumberofElements` is changed to 0 and so the search function outputs incorrect results.

Note: All values I use are from 0-255 for u8 and only use negative with s8 (small numbers that don't even reach 50 or -50)

Comment: `scanf("%d", &NumberofElements);` is not valid code. "%d" expects a pointer to `int` and `NumberofElements` is a `u8`. you can do `scanf("%hhd", &NumberofElements);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the line you mentioned:

```
scanf("%d", &NumbertoSearchfor);
```

The `%d` format specifier to `scanf` is expecting an `int *` but you're instead passing in a `char *`.  Using a mismatched format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What is most likely happening in practice is that since a `char` is 1 byte and an `int` is (most likely) 4 bytes, `scanf` is writing 4 bytes worth of data at the given address, writing past the bounds of the variable in question into nearby variables.

You should instead use `%hhd` if you want `scanf` to read a value and put it in a `char`.

```
scanf("%hhd", &NumbertoSearchfor);
```

There are similar errors elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. You have no clue how much easier you just made life.  I've been struggling with this issue for so long with multiple programs and this just saved me